# Retrieve :id from url and use it as a form value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, put, swig-template

I am trying to get it so that when a user goes to `/checkout` that they can enter a number and user then save it. My issue is having it so when they are at the view all / show page that they click `checkout` and it takes them to `/checkout/:id`. I got that part which is easy but how do I access that ID from the URL inside my template?

Here is my form:

```
<form role="form-inline"action="/dashboard/it/expendable/checkout?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Number of units checked out</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="name" name="checkoutNum" placeholder="# Units">
 </div><!-- Number Checkout -->
</form>
```

My route:

```
// checkout expendable  
  app.get('/dashboard/it/expendable/checkout/:id',
    setRedirect({auth: '/login'}),
    isAuthenticated,
    (req, res, next) => {

    next();
    },
    setRender('dashboard/it/checkoutExpendable'),
    dashboard.getDefault);
```

I need the ID from the URL to be able to be passed to my `PUT` route to save the data mainly the number of units taken. I plan to have it so it creates a new checked out `document` then updates the expendable quantity from an existing `document`.

Comment: It should be in `req.params.id` More examples here under request heading: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: @Mark_M That is for my node.js code, how can I get that into my template? Should I in my `GET` route put a variable and pass that through?

Comment: @Mark_M Just tried what my previous comment said and it worked, thank you. I never thought to pass it as a variable till you mentioned the `req`.

Comment: Yes that works, you can also add them to `res.locals` which is available to routes. `res.locals.id =  “Foo”`

Comment: That is how I did it yes, I guess variable was the wrong way to put it. but I did use `res.locals.requestID`